Возможность отображения текущего местоположения в Yandex MapKit для iOS
Не нашел ни в документации ни в коде возможность отображения текущего местоположения на карте (круглая метка по-центру) подобно опции myLocationEnabled для Google Maps iOS SDK. При этом в приложении Яндекс карт эта метка очевидно присутствует:

Планируют ли разработчики добавить данную опцию?

Для определения местоположения можно использовать LocationManager и LocationListener.
Вижу, что на StackOverflow есть пример решения такой задачи.

Речь идёт об отображении метки с текущим местоположением (см скрин), а не об определении текущего местоположения программно.
